# $f_n(z)={z^n\over n}$, $z\in D$ open unit disk then

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$f_n(z)={z^n\over n}$, $z\in D$ open unit disk then

1.$\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $D$?

2.$f_n$ and $f'_n$ converges uniformly on $D$?

3.$\sum f'_n$ converges on $D$ pointwise?

4.$f_n''(z)$ does not converge unless $z=0$

clearly $1$ is false as $\sum {1\over n}$ is divergent, I know $f_n$ and $f'_n$ converges to $0$ on $D$ but dont know if the convergence is uniform or not, so not sure about $2$, $3$ is true as $|z|<1$  infinite geometric series $\sum z^{n-1}$ converges!, $4\Rightarrow$ $f_n''(z)=(n-1)z^{n-2}$ is convergent to $0$ on $D$ as $|z|<1$ so $4$ is false

Comment: Your answers for (1) and (3) contradict each other. You say that (3) converges and (1) diverges, yet (3) clearly bounds (1). Re-check (1), and note that it says *open* unit disc.

Comment: @fgp Note that (1) requires **uniform** convergence and (3) pointwise ...

Comment: @martini True, I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what follows $\|\cdot\|_{C^0(D)}$ denotes the supremum norm $\|f\|_{C^0(D)} = \sup_{z\in D}|f(z)|$.

Your reasoning for (1) is right, perhaps you should mention that $\| \sum_{n=1}^N f_n\|_{C^0(D)} \ge \sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n$, so as the partial sums are unbounded, we cannot have uniform convergence.

We have $\|f_n\|_{C^0(D)} = \frac 1n\to 0$, so $f_n \to 0$ uniformly. For $f_n'(z) = z^{n-1}$, note that $f_n'(z) \to 0$ pointwise, but $\|f_n'\|_{C^0(D)} = 1$, if $(f_n')$ were uniformly convergent, necessarily $f_n' \to 0$, contradicting $\|f_n'\|_{C^0(D)} \to 1$.

Yes, as you said, on $D$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n-1} = \frac 1{1-z}$ pointwise (as fgp mentioned in his comment, not uniformly, but this isn't asked).

For (4) we have, as you say, $f_n''(z) = (n-1)z^{n-2} \to 0$ for $z\in D$.